# No parameterless constructor defined for this object in Social login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am Implementing Social login in my application but I am getting an error "No parameterless constructor defined for this object".I am not able to find out the reason behind this.can any one tell me exactly what haapening.My Controller is as follows:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
    if (!result.IsSuccessful)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
    }

    if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

    }

    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // If the current user is logged in add the new account
        OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
        string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
        ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new RegisterExternalLoginModel { UserName = result.UserName, ExternalLoginData = loginData });
    }
}
```

and I am getting an error in this line:

```
if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
```

Please Let me know..

Comment: Are you using dependency injection?

Comment: no..Simple Auth.config File to introduce the Social login